# Trouble parsing a sentence with Java Pattern matcher

Tags: java, regex

my regex is not good at the best of times, and I've been struggling with this for a few hours now. I want to parse a sentence into parts which are mostly words, but include numbers with decimals and/or quoted text.

I have a testbed:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Ihave        = "a.X='Foo123. != was here' and "
                        + " T!= v or "
                        + " cat <> dog and "
                        + " x>-15 and "
                        + " \"Peter and Paul\"=\"Mary\" and "
                        + " y< 15.23 bah ";

    String[] Iwant = {"a.X"
                            , "="
                            , "'Foo123. != was here'"
                            , "and" // accidently left off on the first stackoverflow posting 
                            , "T"
                            , "!="
                            , "v"
                            , "or"
                            , "cat"
                            , "<>"
                            , "dog"
                            , "and"
                            , "x"
                            , ">"
                            , "-15"
                            , "and"
                            , "\"Peter and Paul\""
                            , "="
                            , "\"Mary\""
                            , "and"
                            , "y"
                            , "<"
                            , "15.23"
                            , "bah"};

    String quotedtext    = "((\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'))";
    String nospaces      = "[^\\s]";
    String alphanumerics = "\\w";

    String trythis = quotedtext + "" 
                    +"|(<>)|(!=)" // group these pairs together
                    +"|("+nospaces+alphanumerics+"*)"
                    +"|(-\\.|[0-9])" // quoted blocks are ok - but the rest are individual characters
                    ;

    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(trythis);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(Ihave);
    int x=0;
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        String parsed = regexMatcher.group();
        if ( x<Iwant.length ) {
            if ( Iwant[x].equals(parsed)) {
                System.out.println(parsed);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(parsed+"                         but not as expected ("+Iwant[x]+")");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(parsed+"              but not as expected");
        }
        x++;
    } 

    System.out.println("\ndone");
}
```

}

and when I run it I get the following:

```
a                         but not as expected (a.X)
.X                         but not as expected (=)
=                         but not as expected ('Foo123. != was here')
'Foo123. != was here'                         but not as expected (and)
and                         but not as expected (T)
T                         but not as expected (!=)
!=                         but not as expected (v)
v                         but not as expected (or)
or                         but not as expected (cat)
cat                         but not as expected (<>)
<>                         but not as expected (dog)
dog                         but not as expected (and)
and                         but not as expected (x)
x                         but not as expected (>)
>                         but not as expected (-15)
-15                         but not as expected (and)
and                         but not as expected ("Peter and Paul")
"Peter and Paul"                         but not as expected (=)
=                         but not as expected ("Mary")
"Mary"                         but not as expected (and)
and                         but not as expected (y)
y                         but not as expected (<)
<                         but not as expected (15.23)
15              but not as expected (bah)
.23              but not as expected
bah              but not as expected

done
```

Although I'm sceptical about the last part of the pattern, everything looks good except the full-stops/decimal points - which are being treated as separate words - how do I fix this (i.e. how do I get "a.X" and "15.23" to stay together)?

I guess the point here for my regex is that the dot shouldn't be treated as a group break.

Any help would be most appreciated.
Thanks
A

Comment: Seems I spoke too soon in my answer. which I've deleted. Somebody already provided a good intro to lexers on StackOverflow.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/17848207/18157  I already voted to close as "too broad", so I can't make this question a dup of that one, but you should definitely check it out.

Comment: Why does the expected result not contain the word 'and' that appears in the first line of `Ihave`, but it does contain that word when it appears elsewhere?

Comment: FredK - sorry you're right.. it should have had the and... I've updated the code above to fix that. Good spot!

Comment: Ok, although this seem to be confused with a need for language parsing and I'm really just asking about why REGEX isn't parsing the dot as part of the word groups, perhaps REGEX can't do this -so I've Java worked around it in the loop instead:
[[code]]
 Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(trythis);
 Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(Ihave);
 int x=1;
 ArrayList results=new ArrayList();
 results.add("");
 while (regexMatcher.find()) {
  if ( parsed.startsWith(".") ) {
   results.add( results.get(x-1)+parsed );
   results.set(x-1, "");
  }
  else {
   results.add(parsed);
  }
  x++;
 } 
[[/code]]